# What would be the query for this

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have an employee table. I want to find the THIRD LETTER of the employee name having last letter as 'H'. What would be the query? Please help me out. By the way, I am using oracle 10g.

Comment: what possible use would this be for anything? is this an exam question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    substr(employee_name, 3, 1 ) as third_letter
FROM employee
WHERE employee_name LIKE '%H'
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to use the `SUBSTR` function

```
SELECT substr( employee_name, 3, 1 ) third_letter
  FROM employee
 WHERE substr( employee_name, -1 ) = 'H'
```